# De Bruijn sequence inside De Bruijn sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, it.information-theory

A binary [De Bruijn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) of index $n$ is a circular sequence $S=a_1a_2\ldots a_{2^n}$, with $a_i∈\{0,1\}$, and such that each of the $2^n$ binary $n$-tuples occurs exactly once in $S$.

> What is the slowest growing sequence $n_1$, $n_2$, $\ldots$ such that there exist the sequence $b_1b_2\ldots$ where $b_1b_2\ldots b_{2^{n_i}}$ is a binary De Bruijn sequence for each $n_i$?

This question already arose in the comments to [Nested De Bruijn Sequences](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67527/nested-de-bruijn-sequences). It is interesting because it can be applied to construction of normal numbers with small discrepancy. In the article ["Concerning some questions of uniform distribution"](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=3266&option_lang=eng) Korobov already used De Bruijn sequences for this purpose but he wrote these sequences one after another.

Comment: I saw some recent new results on de Bruijn sequence constructions by these guys: http://www.cis.uoguelph.ca/~sawada/papers/new_construction_binary.pdf

Comment: The same algorithm was proposed by Korobov in the mentioned paper (1950).